# Correct way of changing a controls text from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have this Thread that counts down from 5 to 0:

```
public static int seconds = 5;
        public static void startTimer()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (seconds > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    seconds--;
                }                
            });
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
```

I want to Update the text value of a label "label1" to the seconds remaining on my main form "Form1",

I currently am using this inside the thread:

```
Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["label1"].Invoke(new Action(() => Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["label1"].Text = str));
```

what would be the correct way of doing this,
I need to create a custom thread for an assignment.

Is this way correct and if not how do I reference the text property of label1 from the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture correct dispatcher and pass it to thread like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int seconds = 5;

        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        Task.Run(async () => 
        { 
            while(seconds > 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                seconds--;
                dispatcher.Invoke(() => textBox1.Text = seconds.ToString());                                        
            }
        });
    }
```

With no dispatcher can be done like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int seconds = 5;

        ISynchronizeInvoke invoker = this;

        Task.Run(async () => 
        { 
            while(seconds > 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                seconds--;
                Action updateMethod = () => textBox1.Text = seconds.ToString();
                invoker.Invoke(updateMethod, new object[] { });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
throws an error "The name 'Dispatcher' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: The Dispatcher is WPF only.

Comment: I am currently using Windows Form Application in Visual Studios

Comment: @Blindy yep, you are right - if you don't have WindowsBase  assembly referenced there is Dispatcher ;/

Comment: if my Thread is in a separate class and not inside the scope of button1_Click, is there a way of using the ISynchronizeInvoke?

Comment: @TyperMan1133 Do you have access to any instance of Control in place where you create this thread? Actually you can assign once control to ISynchronizeInvoker and pass it to thread.